# Expected number of sinks in a tree

Tags: expected-value, trees

Consider a tree *T* with *n* nodes. A random direction is assigned to each edge uniformly at random independently. A node *v* is a sink if all the edges incident on *v* receive direction pointing towards *v*. Find the expected number of sinks.

I am told that the answer is Ω(n),  may I know why?

Answer (score 0):

Tree with $n$ nodes has $n - 1$ edges and so $2n - 2$ pairs (edge, node incident to this edge). If the tree has at least $2/3n$ nodes with degree $3$ or more, it has at least $2/3n \cdot 3 = 2n > 2n - 2$ pairs. Thus number of nodes of degree more than $2$ is at most $2/3n$, and thus number of nodes of degree at most $2$ is at least $1/3n$.

Note that node with degree at most $2$ has probability at least $1/4$ to be a sink. So expected number of sinks is at least $1/3n \cdot 1/4 = 1/12 n = \Omega(n)$.

Comment: The number of nodes of degree 1 or 2 is at least n/2. I believe at the count of degree for at least 2/3 nodes with degree 3 or more, you have overlooked the nodes with degree 2.

Comment: It is (actually I think having $k$ nodes with degree 3+ implies having at least $2k+1$ nodes with degree 1 or 2), but for $\Omega(n)$ number of sinks we don't need that estimation, and it's slightly harder to prove. I don't think we need to look at nodes with degree 2 when making such upper bound for nodes of degree 3 or more.